# POJO + variable contraints on declaration from property files (with Lombok & Spring)

Tags: java, spring, constraints, pojo, properties-file

In a Java+Spring project, we have a properties file, and I would like to add there some constraints to limit a text length (limit input to store in a String) in a POJO, a incoming data container; for what I use javax.validation.constraints.

Basic version without properties file usage for this:

```
...
import lombok.Data;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
...
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DummyPojo {
  @Size(min = 15, max = 100)
  private String description;
  ...
  public DummyPojo(...){...}
  ...
}
```

Due to it will be applied to multiple POJOs with the same restrictions, the objective is to store in a single unique point the min size value and the max size value, for that I thought in the properties file. I though in doing something like this:

```
...
import lombok.Data;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
...
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DummyPojo {
  @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @Autowired
  private DataConstraintsProperties properties;
    @Size(min = properties.getMinTextSize, max = properties.getMaxTextSize)
    private String description;
      ...
    public DummyPojo(...){...}
      ...
}
```

But that would not work, obviously, indeed, the @Autowired would require something else, like a @Component or a @Service Bean, not a @Data POJO.

Do you know if it would be possible in same way to make the POJO able to load those properties file values in declaration time *(although I'm afraid it's not possible)*, or if I should use some other method (considered elegant from a SW Engineering point of view, or, at least, not considered an [anti-pattern, such as Constants class](http://odi.ch/prog/design/newbies.php#47))?

Thank you very much and best regards

Answer (score 2):

add min and max property in properties file like below

```
min=8

max=19
```

and get it through in your pojo class

```
@Value("${min}")
private String gMin;

@Value("${max}")
private String gMax;
```

and use this variable like below code

```
@Size(min = gMin, max = gMax)
private String description;
```

Comment: Thanks, but from where do I have to import @Value, Spring or Lombok?
I tried both, and it only accepts it with spring...beans.factory.annotation.Value, and it doesn't work with @Size(..., max =  gMax), it doesn't compile: 
"Error:(..) java: element value must be a constant expression"

Comment: You dont have to import lombok it's a spring-boot functionality to read properties file data use below format to right a code.

Comment: you have to import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Comment: public class SamplePropertyLoadingTest {
    @Autowired
    private SampleProperty sampleProperty;
    @Value("${prefix.stringProp1}")
    private String stringProp1;

Comment: your idea is good, but, unfortunately, @Size value is set at compilation time, while the properties file is loaded at runtime, for that, some company experienced Java developers or I could not be found the way to make it work, I am not sure if I miss something, or maybe I just explained wrong before.
Finally, we will hardcode that kind of limitations, as an exception.
Thanks for your help in any case.